# Rails: How to override stylesheet_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mixins

I've been trying to override Rails' `stylesheet_path` helper, but I haven't found a way how. I can't just open the `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper` module and override it there, because Rails won't pick up my new method.

I know it's probably because the module gets mixed in, so how do I get around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this so that `stylesheet_link_tag` will result in something different from normal?  If so, just override *that* in a helper :)

Alternatively, if you really want to override `stylesheet_path`, you need to also redefine the alias, as, curiously, it's only accessed via its alias (in Rails 2.3.2). For example, I put this in `environment.rb` and it worked:

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module AssetTagHelper
      def stylesheet_path(source)
        "x"
      end
      alias_method :path_to_stylesheet, :stylesheet_path
    end
  end
end
```

I personally wouldn't go this route but it should work for you if you need it :)